# Array.splice not working in firefox console

Tags: javascript, arrays

Trying the following code from the MDN site

```
var myFish = ['angel', 'clown', 'mandarin', 'surgeon'];

// removes 0 elements from index 2, and inserts 'drum'
var removed = myFish.splice(2, 0, 'drum');
```

Doesn't assign to remove the expected output of splice `['angel', 'clown', 'drum', 'mandarin', 'surgeon']`, but instead and empty array `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused by the return value of `splice`. It does not return the modified array, but the elements removed. In this case, you removed none, so if you log `removed`, you get an empty `Array`.

```
var myFish = ['angel', 'clown', 'mandarin', 'surgeon'];
var removed = myFish.splice(2, 0, 'drum');
console.log(myFish);
console.log(removed);
```

Output:

```
Array [ "angel", "clown", "drum", "mandarin", "surgeon" ]
Array [  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.prototype.splice operates on the original array.